# Build (and Debug) ASP.NET Web Application in a non-default folder location

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution with an ASP.NET Web Application project.  I want to change the default output folder, of said project, to *$(SolutionDir)\WebApps\$(ProjectName)\bin*.  This I can do and when I build I get the expected assembly files in this folder.  It doesn't copy the content files (aspx, etc.) to the parent folder but I have managed to fix this by hacking the project.csproj file with a custom build target.

The problem is I want to be able to debug this application using the ASP.NET Development Server, by pressing F5 in VS2008.  Unfortunately the ASP.NET Dev server starts, has a "Physical Path", in the project directory rather than the parent of the output directory.

Is there any way to build my web application to a different output folder but still run the asp.net dev server to debug my site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, but it isn't pretty.  The process I used is given below.

1. Unloaded the project in VS.
2. Manually edited the .csproj file to include a post build action that basically copies the content files (aspx, etc.) to the parent of the output folder.
3. For the debug options I set the project to launch an external executable.  The Asp.Net Development server.  Also manually set the url to launch.

What I learnt?  I wouldn't do this, I'd just stick with the default and create an install/web deployment project instead.